# Rails updating foreign key for a has_one relationship to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, belongs-to, has-one

I have an Anexo model with has_one relationship with an Attachment model

```
class Anexo < ApplicationRecord
  validates :descricao, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_one :attachment,  dependent: :restrict_with_error, validate: true
end

class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :nome, :tamanho, :anexo, presence: true
  belongs_to :anexo 
end
```

In my AnexosController,

```
def update
   @anexo.build_attachment(attachment_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @anexo.update(anexo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @anexo, notice: 'Anexo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @anexo }
     else
       format.html { render :edit }
       format.json { render json: @anexo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

When I am creating a new record everythig is working fine and a proper error message is displayed when I left the atachment blank.

When I edit this registry, and do not select any attachment, it displays the message, but the foreign key is set to nil.

If I cancel the operation and come back, the record has been updated and the anexo no longer has the old attachment.

Would you like to know if you can prevent this update from happening in build_attachment?

Comment: can you please share you `update form` code i.e app/views/anexos/edit.html.erb

Comment: `@anexo.build_attachment(attachment_params)` perform this only there is params present in attachment_params


`@anexo.build_attachment(attachment_params) if attachment_params.present?`

Comment: @SampatBadhe If I check the attachment_params, it will allow you to save the attachment with the old attachment value. I need it to display the validation message of the associated class, displaying that it has no attachments, but without updating the foreign key for nil.

Comment: @NimishGupta I do not think edit form might have something that causes this problem, but it follows the code below,

`<h1>Editing Anexo</h1>

<%= render 'form', anexo: @anexo %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @anexo %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', anexos_path %>`

Comment: Check by adding `required` to has_one relation

`has_one :attachment,  dependent: :restrict_with_error, validate: true, required: true`

Comment: @SampatBadhe It does not work, I added the required one in has_one relation, however it continues the same way, not allowing update Anexo without the attachment, but updating the foreign key to nil.